# regex match a string left of a c++ comment

Tags: regex, comments, regex-group

I'm looking for a pattern to extract a string left of a c++ comment and the comment itself. The problem is, the left side can contain a single slash as well.

Example:

`"abc/def//comment"`

As a result, I would like to have 2 groups which contains the left side of the comment and the comment itself:

1. abc/def
2. //comment

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with a regex? Sometimes doing stuff programmatically is more easy (and this seems one of them).

Comment: @nightcracker: what's so hard about doing this with a regex?

Comment: @siride: String literals, macros, nested comments, etc. Language syntax usually can't be parsed with a regex (take HTML).

Comment: @nightcracker: yes, I know, but there is no arbitrary nesting here.  Once you get a double slash, everything to the end of the line is in a comment, period.  To deal with double slashes before, you can use lookahead and other tricks to deal with slashes embedded in strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're processing the file line-by-line, this regex will do what you want:

```
((?:(?!//).)*)(//.*)
```

or simply:

```
(.*?)(//.*)
```

I.e., group 1 contains `abc/def` and group 2 contains `//comment`.

Be aware that when this fails with string literals and multi-line comments (to name just two pit-falls):

```
"a string with // in it"

/*
// not a comment!
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "abc/def//comment" | sed -r 's|(.*)//(.*)|\1 //\2|'
abc/def //comment
```

What about multiple pairs of slashes? Comments inside Strings are ok?

Comment: Be careful: the first greedy `.*` will consume `a // b` from a string with more than one `//` in it, like: `"a // b // c"`.

Comment: That's why I asked 'What about multiple pairs of slashes'. Can you see it. :)